# C++ String

Tags: строки, c++

Есть задача : Если в консоль передать 'd', то удалить символ после 'l', если  передать 'i', то вставить после 'l' '_'. 
Задача простая, но С++ на то и С++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char condition = 'd';
    //cin >> condition;
    string hello = "Hello World";
    size_t found = hello.find('l') + 1;
    while(found != string::npos){
        if(condition == 'd'){
            hello.erase(found, 0);
            found = hello.find('l') + 1;
        }
        else if(condition == 'i'){
            hello.insert(found,  1, '_');
            found = hello.find('l', found) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Что не так ?

Comment: Сначала надо проверять found на npos, а потом прибавлять 1.

Comment: `hello.erase(found, 0);` удалит 0 символов, то есть ни одного

Comment: Для вашего примера, надо ли удалять символ после второго `l`? Потому что если сканировать слева направо, как у вас, сначала удалится второе `l`, и сканирование не дойдёт до него.

Comment: После первого